# VBA-Access: Some of my insert queries work, others do not, and my final update query also does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vba, sql-update, sql-insert, dao, ms-access-2013

Here is the code.  Because I'm really just trying to make it work at this point, it's all directly within the click event.  I'm not getting any errors.  It just isn't fully working:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateTask_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'open db and specify DAO methods
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb 'because the db is already open, don't need: OpenDatabase("FollowUp_Test.mdb")

    'this will eventually be accessed a different way
    Dim userId As Integer
    userId = 1

    'INSERT task and return id
    Dim qryInsertTask As String
    qryInsertTask = "INSERT INTO Task (applicant_info_id) VALUES (NULL);"
    Dim qryTaskId As String
    qryTaskId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim taskId As Integer

    'INSERT applicant info row and return id
    Dim qryInsertAppInfo As String
    qryInsertAppInfo = "INSERT INTO ApplicantInfo " _
                & "(task_id, app_first_name, app_last_name, applicant_id_number, " _
                & "account_id_number, issue_id_number) VALUES " _
                & "('" & taskId & "', '" & txtAppFirstName.Value & "', '" & txtAppLastName.Value & "', " _
                & "" & txtAppId.Value & ", " & txtAcctId.Value & ", " & txtIssueId.Value & ");"
    Dim qryAppInfoId As String
    qryAppInfoId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim appInfoId As Integer

    'INSERT owner row and return id
    Dim qryInsertOwner As String
    qryInsertOwner = "INSERT INTO Ownership " _
                & "(task_id, user_id, ownership_date, " _
                & "task_owned) VALUES (" & taskId & ", " & userId & ", " _
                & "#" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#, " & True & ");"
    Dim qryOwnerId As String
    qryOwnerId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim ownerId As Integer

    'get values from comboboxes
    Dim actionId As Integer
    actionId = cboFolder.Value
    Dim monTypeId As Integer
    monTypeId = cboMonetaryType.Value
    'MsgBox (actionId & ", " & monTypeId)

    'INSERT schedule row and return id
    Dim qryInsertSchedule As String
    qryInsertSchedule = "INSERT INTO Schedule " _
                & "(task_id, due_date) VALUES " _
                & "(" & taskId & ",  #" & Format(txtFollowUpDt.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#);"
    Dim qryScheduleId As String
    qryScheduleId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim scheduleId As Integer

    'INSERT TaskHistory row and return id
    Dim qryInsertTaskHistory As String
    qryInsertTaskHistory = "INSERT INTO TaskHistory " _
                & "(task_id, create_user_id, create_date) VALUES " _
                & "(" & taskId & ", " & userId & ", #" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#);"
    Dim qryTaskHistoryId As String
    qryTaskHistoryId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim taskHistoryId As Integer

    'INSERT comment row and return id
    Dim qryInsertComment As String
    qryInsertComment = "INSERT INTO Comments " _
                & "(comment_text) VALUES ('" & txtComment.Value & "');"
    Dim qryCommentId As String
    qryCommentId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim commentId As Integer

    'INSERT EventLog row and return id
    Dim qryInsertEventLog As String
    qryInsertEventLog = "INSERT INTO EventLog " _
                & "(task_id, action_id, user_id, mon_type_id, comment_id, " _
                & "event_date) VALUES (" & taskId & ", " & actionId & ", " & userId & ", " & monTypeId & ", " _
                & "" & commentId & ", #" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#);"
    Dim qryEventLogId As String
    qryEventLogId = "SELECT @@Identity"
    Dim eventLogId As Integer

    'UPDATE task with all the id's created
    Dim qryUpdateTask As String
    qryUpdateTask = "UPDATE Task SET applicant_info_id = " & appInfoId & ", " _
                & "ownership_id = " & ownerId & ", action_id = " & actionId & ", mon_type_id = " & monTypeId & ", " _
                & "schedule_id = " & scheduleId & ", event_id = " & eventLogId & ", task_history_id = " & taskHistoryId & " " _
                & "WHERE task_id = " & taskId & ";"

    'run the queries
    dbs.Execute qryInsertTask
    taskId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryTaskId)(0)
    MsgBox (taskId)
    'MsgBox (taskId & ", " & txtAppFirstName.Value & ", " & txtAppLastName.Value & ", " _
    '            & txtAppId.Value & ", " & txtAcctId.Value & ", " & txtIssueId.Value)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertAppInfo
    appInfoId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryAppInfoId)(0)
    'MsgBox (appInfoId)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertOwner
    ownerId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryOwnerId)(0)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertSchedule
    scheduleId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryScheduleId)(0)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertTaskHistory
    taskHistoryId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryTaskHistoryId)(0)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertComment
    commentId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryCommentId)(0)
    dbs.Execute qryInsertEventLog
    eventLogId = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryEventLogId)(0)
    MsgBox (appInfoId & ", " & ownerId & ", " & actionId & ", " & monTypeId & ", " & _ 
        & scheduleId & ", " & eventLogId & ", " & taskHistoryId & ", " & taskId)
    dbs.Execute qryUpdateTask

    'dereference and close
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

ExitSub:
    'rs.Close
    Exit Sub
    Set dbs = Nothing

ErrHandler:

  MsgBox "Something's wrong: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Make sure all entries are in the correct format." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
  & "Error", , "Validation Error"
    'dereference and close on error
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Resume ExitSub
    Resume
  End Sub
```

I've included a couple msgboxes that all present the right information from what I've saved in the various variables, so I don't know why it's not working when I run the update query, at least.  I'm pretty new to filling a database from VBA, so I imagine it's something related to how I'm using accessing the database.  I also suspect that my dates are an issue, but I can't figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Include the `dbFailOnError` option when you execute those statements like this: `dbs.Execute qryInsertOwner, dbFailOnError`  In some situations, that option will give you give you better information when a statement fails.

Comment: Thank you, putting that in there did help with catching a number of problems that required changes on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.  I just had to use the TempVars collection.  I don't understand why that was necessary, but apparently that's the way to access the variables stored in the identity values from the inserts.

I was able to save the variable like this:

```
TempVars("tempTaskId").Value = taskId
```

And then access it in the query like this:

```
TempVars!tempTaskId.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT @@Identity"
```

is not *Access SQL*, so replace that with some value, or remove it completely if the field is an AutoNumber.

Comment: [SELECT @@Identity in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+SELECT+%40%40Identity)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I agree that my problem now is related to @@Identity.  Thing is, I can see that it is getting the values of the various autonumber id's generated and storing them in the variables I created for them.  Then, when I try to use those variables in a few of my inserts and in my final update, it's like they don't exist.